# Can I use a complex datatype with an EF-provided WCF Data Services without telling EF about it?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

I am using an Entity Framework-provided WCF DataService to expose an OData endpoint. I want to create a Service Operation that returns a new type. But I get:

> The exception message is 'Unable to load metadata for return type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyNamespace+MyNewType]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyNamespace+MyNewType] FlightHours()'.'. See server logs for more details.

How can I let the DataService know I want it to grok MyNewType?  Do I have to hackily make a fake entity on the EF DataContext, or can I simply "add" it in somehow?  [This post came up with that hack](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/e473e2b9-f385-412d-9aba-44acf9719fd8) but I was hoping things had changed or that they missed something.

Update with relevant links:

- I assume [WCF DataService with Entity Framework: TimeSpan support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454747/wcf-dataservice-with-entity-framework-timespan-support) would be solved the same way.
- [This MSDN discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/adodotnetdataservices/thread/1225c65f-089d-4ad7-846a-71626f2b2282) implies that methods like this exist for Reflection and Custom sources but make no mention of EF.
- Jun 2013 update: Thanks to @dgorissen who found this possible counterexample: [WCF Data Services 5.0 Workaround for returning POCOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11421648/237091)  I haven't had a chance to test this myself, and I don't know why it would work, but maybe it will...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no other way than to teach the EF that such a type exists. When you use the EF provider for WCF DS, the entire metadata comes solely from EF, WCF DS doesn't modify it in any (meaningful) way.

Comment: If I want to create dynamic data services (like reshaping some of my data on the fly) that share an OData endpoint with EF, can I somehow build a custom data provider that offers the EF stuff and also my additional dynamic stuff? Is that excruciating to create?

Comment: It is definitely possible, but somewhat hard. The main problem is not the metadata part (that's just tedious), it's the IQueryable part of the custom provider. Due to slight differencies in IQueryable behavior WCF DS generates a little bit different LINQ queries when running against EF provider and customer/reflection provider. It is possible to "fix" these using custom visitors, it's just a bit tricky. On the other hand most queries will work even without these tricks.

Comment: Do you have a relevant link to the official docs? Im still somewhat confused by e.g. this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421648/wcf-data-services-5-0-workaround-for-returning-pocos

Comment: You can probably search MSDN as good as I, and I don't have a better link to this particular issue. As for the other question... it is highly likely that the code there was using reflection provider (everything defined as classes, no EF context directly) in which case the provider can add types ad-hoc from the class.

Comment: This whole area is a know limitation of WCF DS. It's currently super hard to mix/match different providers in one endpoint. I know for sure that the product team is working on this. In the 5.5 release the EF and Reflection providers are now public. So it's much easier to modify their behavior. So you should be able to do the above without a need for a custom provider all up, just modify the EF provider to support what you need.